# JSON_ARRAYAGG not working properly with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, group-by, grouping, where-clause

**I have two tables Contractor Users as cu & Parkings as pak. But when we search the parking name our contractor parking also get affected by this search**

**Contractor Users as cu**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom |
| 2 | Jerry |
| 3 | Jake |

**Parkings as pak**

| id | name | contractor_ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | parking_a | 1 |
| 2 | parking_b | 1,3 |
| 3 | parking_c | 1,2 |

**Query before any search**

```
 SELECT cu.name, JSON_ARRAYAGG(pak.name) as user_parkings 
FROM contractor_users as cu 
LEFT JOIN parkings as pak ON FIND_IN_SET(cu.id, pak.contractor_ids) 
WHERE cu.name IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY cu.id
```

**Result of Above query**

| name | user_parkings |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | ['parking_a','parking_b', 'parking_c'] |
| Jerry | ['parking_c'] |
| Jake | ['parking_b',] |

**Add search parking name filter in WHERE clause**

```
SELECT cu.name, JSON_ARRAYAGG(pak.name) as user_parkings 
FROM contractor_users as cu 
LEFT JOIN parkings as pak ON FIND_IN_SET(cu.id, pak.contractor_ids) 
WHERE cu.name IS NOT NULL AND pak.name = 'parking_a' 
GROUP BY cu.id
```

**Result of Above query**

| name | user_parkings |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | ['parking_a'] |

**So here is the problem you see user_parkings column also filtered but what I want after adding the search**

| name | user_parkings |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | ['parking_a','parking_b', 'parking_c'] |

Comment: Storing the data in CSV format is bad idea. Normalize your structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add search parking name filter in WHERE clause

This is incorrect - you need to check the value presence after the aggregation, so the condition must be placed not into WHERE but into HAVING.

Test, for example, this:

```sql
SELECT cu.name, JSON_ARRAYAGG(pak.name) as user_parkings 
FROM contractor_users as cu 
LEFT JOIN parkings as pak ON FIND_IN_SET(cu.id, pak.contractor_ids) 
WHERE cu.name IS NOT NULL  
GROUP BY cu.id
HAVING MAX(pak.name = 'parking_a')
```